# picard's method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given 1st order ODE, 
 $ \frac{dy}{dx} =x+y, \ y_{0}=1 $,  solve  by **picard's** method using $y_{0}(x)= \cos x $ as initial approximation. $$ $$ I don't know how to start **picard's method** if the initial approximation is not constant. Can anyone **just start the process**.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Compute
$$
y_1(x)=1+\int_0^xf(s,y_0(s))\,ds=1+\int_0^x(s+\cos s)\,ds
$$
etc.